# Показать/спрятать элемент

Tags: swift

У нас есть View в котором отображаются разные поля Вида:

```
UILabel UITextField
UILabel UITextField
```

И так далее. Мне надо, чтобы при заполнении определённого поля UITextField (назовём его ShowTextField) под ним появлялось ещё одно, которое раньше было скрытым. Выставление параметра hidden в true/false я знаю как делать, но мне надо, что бы другие поля (которые раньше находились под ShowTextField) опускались ниже...

Быстренько набросал на jQuery код, что бы было более понятно - http://jsfiddle.net/wfjuy75u/

То у меня друг под другом находятся поля и текстовые поля и мне надо, при клике (а в идеале при заполнении) определённого поля - опускать те, что под ним ещё ниже, что бы поместилось новое.

Comment: предполагаю, что в вопросе опечатка - `UITextField` а не `UITextLabel`

Comment: Да, вы правы, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

что то я видимо не понял вопрос. вам надо менять `frame` всех ваших вью, которые ниже нужного:

```
let frame:CGRect = self.view.frame
frame.origin.y += 30 // ну например 30.
                     //правильнее будет использовать высоту скрытого поля
self.view.frame = frame
```

Чтобы показать новое поле, когда что-то введено в нужный UITextField, надо объявить свой класс делегатом для того текст филда, и проверять ввод новых символов в `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)`. когда что-то введено в нужном вам поле, показывайте скрытое поле и сдвигайте все, что под ним.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать

Comment: Не получается двигать элементы таким образом. Точнее на некоторых экранах они двигаются, но на котором должны появляться - нет. Может быть это связано с тем, что у меня прописаны constraint по удалённости от элемента (который сверху) ?
Потому что когда я пишу:
        `print(MyLabel.frame)
        MyLabel.frame = CGRectMake(160, 200, 60, 40)
        print(MyLabel.frame)`

Мне выводятся разные значения (которые были сначала, а потом те, что я указал), но позиция элемента на экране не меняется

Comment: Тогда ответ HunTer255 должен помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно лучше в этом случае использовать Autolayout, расположить все `UITextField` и задать им констрейны, для по умолчанию скрытых `UITextField` выставить в коде при загрузке высоту 0, а при вводе текста в нужный `UITextField` увеличивать констрейн высоты скрытого элемента, можно даже с анимацией. В этом случае отпадет необходимость расчетов сдвига других `UITextField`, всё будет делаться на автомате.

Comment: А вы не могли бы подсказать как это всё делается? Или скинуть ссылку на статью, а то я не совсем ещё умею работать с Autolayout.

Comment: Подсказать не могу, инструмент довольно объемный и о всех возможностях и тонкостях коротко не расскажешь. На русском посоветую посмотреть уроки на youtube, от "Konstantin Kokorin". На английском есть несколько хороших статей тут: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1